# ASP.NET | C# | Dropdownlist SelectedItem to Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I want to add ASP.NET code-behind C# Dropdownlist selected value to the SQL Server database. 
I'm using a stored procedure and in SQL Server it works when I execute the procedure.

I have added database connection (dal.class) file to the VS project.

My code in dal.class is

```
 public void SaveDelData(int pkg_no, int pkg_cat_id, String reference_no, String sender, String receiver_name, String receiver_address, int area_id, int city_id, int zone_id, String date, String telephone, bool isDelete)
 {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmdGetItem = new SqlCommand();
                cmdGetItem.Connection = con;
                cmdGetItem.CommandText = "SavedeliveryData"; 
                cmdGetItem.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pkg_no", pkg_no);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pkg_cat_id", pkg_cat_id);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sender", sender);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiver_name", receiver_name);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiver_address", receiver_address);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area_id", area_id);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city_id", city_id);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zone_id", zone_id);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", telephone);
                cmdGetItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isDelete", isDelete);

                con.Open();
                cmdGetItem.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

and I have 4 dropdownlists on the design page which get data from the other table for particular data.

my C# code is

```
dataAccess data = new dataAccess();

        int pkg_id; 
        if (packageid.Text == string.Empty || packageid.Text == "")
            pkg_id = -1;
        else
            pkg_id = Int32.Parse(packageid.Text);

        string sData1 = this.category.SelectedValue;
        string sData2 = this.area.SelectedValue;
        string sData3 = this.city.SelectedValue;
        string sData4 = this.zone.SelectedValue;

     // string cat = category.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
     // string areaa = area.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
     //string cityy = city.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
     // string zonee = zone.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

        data.SaveDelData(pkg_id, sData1, sender_name.Text, receivername.Text, receiver_address.Text, sData2,sData3,sData4, date.Text, telephone.Text, false);
```

I want to send send dropdownlist selected item to the database but it give the error in

```
data.SaveDelData(pkg_id, sData1, sender_name.Text, receivername.Text, receiver_address.Text, sData2,sData3,sData4, date.Text, telephone.Text, false);
```

as

> No overload for method 'SaveDelData' takes 11 arguments

How can I fix this one ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Doesn't any of the answers help ?

Comment: got it , now the problem is get the selected values to the database :D

Comment: edit question and explain again in detail, what is the problem, where it is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void SaveDelData(int pkg_no, int pkg_cat_id, String reference_no, String sender, String receiver_name, String receiver_address, int area_id, int city_id, int zone_id, String date, String telephone, bool isDelete)
    {


     }
```

Obviously you can count 12 parameters in the above function

so you are missing one and i guess its pkg_cat_id

```
data.SaveDelData(pkg_id,(integer type parameter here 'pkg_cat_id'), sData1, sender_name.Text, receivername.Text, receiver_address.Text, sData2,sData3,sData4, date.Text, telephone.Text, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your call to 'SaveDelData' method  and give it 12 arguments. You are only passing 11! I think you are missing the pkg_cat_id?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply geedubb ,  Can you explain more about the answer ? , where i should change it ?

Comment: Check your data.SaveDelData call. It only has 11 args

Comment: think you are missing the pkg_cat_id

Answer (score 0):

As per following function definition you need to pass 12 parameters while making a call.

```
public void SaveDelData(int pkg_no, int pkg_cat_id, String reference_no, String sender, String receiver_name, String receiver_address, int area_id, int city_id, int zone_id, String date, String telephone, bool isDelete)
```

In the following call you are passing only 11 parameters.

```
data.SaveDelData(pkg_id, sData1, sender_name.Text, receivername.Text, receiver_address.Text, sData2,sData3,sData4, date.Text, telephone.Text, false);
```

In above call first parameter is package Id, second is selected category and the third is the name of the sender. But as per function definition third parameter should be a string reference Id. So I think you missed to pass that reference id. Add it in your parameter list and it work fine.

Regards,

Nitin Joshi